# How does setting the value of a Property in the constructor call work with JsonProperty?

Tags: c#, constructor, attributes

This line of code works, but I'm not sure why it does.

```
[JsonProperty("id", Required = Required.Always)]
```

To me this seems to be setting a value of a `Property` in the `JsonProperty` class. Is this unique only to `Attributes` and declaring attributes?

Looking at the `JsonProperty` class I can see that the constructor is written like so

```
 public JsonPropertyAttribute(string propertyName);
```

Again, how does this work? It seems to run contrary to how I've written C# for the past year.. Is it magic within the `Attribute` class or is it actually a feature of C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [**Named Arguments**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) and they are not unique to Attributes.

C# 4 introduced them:

> Named arguments enable you to specify an argument for a particular parameter by associating the argument with the parameter's name rather than with the parameter's position in the parameter list.

C# 6.0 introduced [**Named Parameters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#positional-and-named-parameters) which are the equivalent for Attributes.

> Attribute classes can have positional parameters and named parameters. Each public instance constructor for an attribute class defines a valid sequence of positional parameters for that attribute class.

Comment: Thank you! It's that second part that I wanted to know, the syntax is different for Attributes. Named Arguments are of the form `name: value`.